# Docker container communication and security

Tags: docker, security, docker-swarm, docker-network

Lets say I have 2 nodes(1 Manager and 1 Worker) and the following compose

```
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - 443:443
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.role==manager
    networks:
      - somenet

  app:
    image: someapp
    deploy:
      mode: global
    networks:
      - somenet

networks:
  default:
    driver: overlay
    driver_opts:
      encrypted: "true"
```

Where NGINX exposes the App to the outside world through HTTPS and forwards the request to one of the app replicas as a reverse proxy.

1. Should the communication between NGINX and App through HTTPS/SSL?
2. Is there any way to sniff the packets inside this overlay network?
3. Is it possible to gain access to any of the containers beside compromising the machine itself?

Comment: __Should the communication between NGINX and App through HTTPS/SSL?__ Read about [TLS Termination](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/TLS_termination_proxy). Simple answer is: It's your choice